# "TypeError: filter_by()" error returned in flask when I am trying to use filter_by()

Tags: forms, flask

I am trying to implement `filter_by()` function of flask. My issue is, when I am trying to use filter for argument, I got the error of:

> `TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I also attached my code to the question.

Main application source code:

```
def login():
    error = None
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.query.filter_by(Email=request.form['email']).first()
        password = User.query.filter_by(Password=request.form['password']).first()
        group = User.query.filter_by(user).first()

        if user is None or password is None :
            session['logged_in'] = False
            flash('Please write your username password')
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            if group=="viewer":
                return redirect(url_for('viewer'))
            elif group=="admin":
                return redirect(url_for('admin'))
            elif group=="employee":
                return redirect(url_for('employee'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

The model which I used for my app :

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    Id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    Password = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True )
    Group = db.Column(db.String(30))
    Tickets = db.relationship('Request', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

Login page source code:

```
<div class="innter-form">
                        <form class="sa-innate-form" method="post">
                            {{ form.csrf_token }}
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ request.form.email }}">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}">
                            <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign In</button>
                            <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: How have you defined your models and where does the error occur?

Comment: Yes I defined it inside in code. The error occurs when I am trying to access. I mean when I type my password and username, in redirection part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter_by is used for queries on the column names

```
...
# this returns a user object 
user = User.query.filter_by(Email=request.form['email']).first()
# you should query based on the Id of User
group = User.query.filter_by(Id=user.Id).first()
```

Comment: Look how `filter_by` method is defined http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html

Comment: Hi thank for response. I edited my model. Could you please check that again? Thanks again

Comment: Yes I think the answers were correct. I understood the value of argument cannot apply to filter_by(). But I don't know how me to take value of form element to filter. Little bit hard because I am fresh in flask

Comment: I assume your LoginForm has `name` field so `user = User.query.filter_by(Name=form.name.data).first()`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is in the line

```
group = User.query.filter_by(user).first()
```

Besides the fact that `filter_by` accepts only keyword arguments - and you supplied only one positional argument to it, I am guessing you should use something different than `User` here (maybe `Group`, not sure since I don't know what models you have defined).

The line I mentioned should look something like

```
group = Group.query.filter_by(user=user).first()
```

Comment: But the only problem is that this is an argument which is passing from frontend side.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for response:

The eror was in group part as mention in above:

```
group = User.query.filter_by(user).first()
```

Instead of this code should be:

```
group = User.query.filter_by(Email=user).first()
```